# background gradients in IE7 with CSS

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-7, gradient

I am using the following bit of CSS to create a linear background gradient. It seems to work just fine in IE8/9, FF, Safari and chrome but not in IE7. IE7 shows a solid (green) background. Here is my code

```
.menu_body a {
  display:block;
  color:#006699;
  background: #008800;
  /* Mozilla: */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0b71a4, #025f8e);
  /* Chrome, Safari:*/
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
            left top, left bottom, from(#0b71a4), to(#025f8e));
  /* MSIE */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
            StartColorStr='#0b71a4', EndColorStr='#025f8e', GradientType=0);
  padding: 1px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In IE<=7, filters won't work unless element has [layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

```
zoom: 1;
```

Be aware that it can break other things, so old good `background-image` might be safe and reliable solution.

Also please note that your CSS lacks gradient properties for Opera, IE10 and updated syntax for Webkit.

Comment: Thanks this worked out great! (couldn't give a vote up though cause i'm a new member, sorry for that) EDIT: for the updated syntax for Webkit I can use -webkit-linear-gradient() right?

Comment: @Schimmel Correct; the syntax is the same as for Firefox and IE10, except for different vendor prefix. By the way, you should be able to accept my answer by clicking on the check box to the left of it.

Comment: @duri - IE10 ? is that something new? :)

Comment: @Dementic There were already 5 released development versions of IE10. I'm kind of surprised you didn't hear about it.

Comment: `zoom: 1`, the solution to 99% of IE7 problems

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
(startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#55FFFF00)
```

This is supported by IE4>

See the MSDN source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if the parameters of this transform are case sensitive - but seeing as most other CSS is, you could try:

```
startColorstr='#0b71a4', endColorstr='#025f8e'
```

Notice the lower-case starting character, and lower-case `str` suffix.

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work. Also tried to give all of the instances lower-casing but that also did not seem to work out.

Comment: Try with `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient`, too - note lower-case `gradient`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer again, but unfortunately this also did not work. I'm really confused because according to the following document this transform should work for Internet Explorer 5.5 or later. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, but check out [this link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), it's a CSS gradient generator which might help you test cases between browsers a little easier.

Comment: this is a very handy tool indeed! Did not know of it's existence.
Thank you for sharing this link!