# CSS HTML backround-image does not appears when using ie6,7 and compatibility view

Tags: html, css, background-image

Hi I have the following problem:
When using all browser, it showing background OK. when using IE6,7 or compatibility view no background image showing.
when removing all "background-image" and just leaving fallback, everything works.
Please help.
Here is the **CSS**:

```
html,body{
     background: #529BCE;
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'); /* fallback */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1D3A62), to(#57A3D5)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* FF3.6+ */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* IE10 */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -o-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* W3C */
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     color:#18364B;
     font-family: Arial,Verdana,Geneva,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     font-size:20px;
     line-height:1.2em;
     margin:0;padding:0;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Is your css file is inside a folder?

Comment: Hi, welcom to SO. Please read the FAQ and find the links about Markdown formatting, you don't need to use HTML to break your lines. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, my css is inside folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try redeclaring the background-image for ie6 and ie7. add the following after your `css` file:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><style>html,body{background:#529bce url("../Img/bg.png") 0 0 no-repeat}</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><style>html,body{background:#529bce url("../Img/bg.png") 0 0 no-repeat}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

That should work, although if you're not seeing a png in IE6, it's because png is not supported. If you're still having trouble, alter the styles for each, so that you know what you are targeting, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

here is the edited css. try this

```
 html,body
    {
       background-color: #57A3D5;
    background-color: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1D3A62), to(#57A3D5));
    background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62 0%, #57A3D5 100%);
    background-image: url('../Img/bg.png'); /* fallback */ 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#18364B;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Geneva,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

    }
```

Comment: applying both the image and background color together will not work in IE

Comment: It is working, but the gradient does not working on no one of the browsers

Comment: Gradient should not work.. http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient, for trying workarounds see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257170/background-gradient-ie7-css-problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<!--[if IE 6]><style type="text/css">html,body{background-color: #529bce; background-image: url('../Img/bg.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat}</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><style type="text/css">html,body{background-color: #529bce; background-image: url('../Img/bg.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the [multiple background image syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds), which is confusing older versions of IE. So instead of this

```
 background-image: url('Img/bg.png'); /* fallback */
 background-image: url('Img/bg.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1D3A62), to(#57A3D5)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
 /* etc */
```

You'll need to remove the `url()` section from the background images with gradients, like so:

```
 background-image: url('Img/bg.png'); /* fallback */
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1D3A62), to(#57A3D5)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* FF3.6+ */
 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* IE10 */
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #1D3A62, #57A3D5); /* W3C */
```

If you need newer browsers to have the gradient *and* `url('Img/bg.png')`, you'll need to find a way to target older versions of IE specifically. I favour [the conditional classes method](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).