# How to use gradient css property that work for IE7?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the following CSS to create a linear background gradient. It seems to work just fine in IE8, FF, Safari and chrome but not in IE7. IE7 shows white background. Here is my code

```
body{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6D1C18 , #AF251B,#6D1C18); /* For Safari   5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #6D1C18, #AF251B,#6D1C18); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #6D1C18, #AF251B, #6D1C18); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6D1C18 , #AF251B, #6D1C18); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#6D1C18', EndColorStr='#AF251B')";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257170/background-gradients-in-ie7-with-css

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is below (example), note the 8-number value for color, instead of 6:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
(startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#55FFFF00)" >
<!-- All of your document elements go in here. -->
</div>
```

Supported by Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0 and above. See the MSDN source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx).